# Predicting sales over time given independent variable

Tags: regression, time-series

I am trying to predict the sales of a product whose past 5 years data is available to me and some independent variable are also available (like the target market size, marketing budget, price, etc.). So now I can't use ARIMA or some time series model nor can I simply use regression to predict the sales. How should I go forward with this?

Comment: Are your independent variable data concurrent, or are you trying to forecast future sales based on current IV data? Do you want to forecast the IV data & then predict sales? Something else?

Comment: The IV are concurrent with the past sales data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a model that will both use independent predictors AND take account of the autocorrelation issues.

A dynamic regression model will do this. There's a good explanation with an example (and snippets of R code) in Hyndman and Athana­sopou­los's book, section 9.1:  https://www.otexts.org/fpp/9/1

The basic steps are these (from the source cited): [image]